# Monitoring VREF+ buffer output in STM32L552

Tags: stm32, embedded, voltage-reference, st, hal

I am working with the STM32L552 microcontroller in a critical application where a portion of the external circuit relies heavily on the 2.5 V VREF+. The stability of this reference voltage is essential, that is if the VREF+ should go above 2.5 V, it would scale other circuits which could lead to undesired behavior.

Is there a way to monitor the VREF+ buffer output using the VREFINT internally within the STM32L552? I specifically want to detect any event where the VREF+ goes above its nominal value. Now the tricky part is that I do not have any pins available where I could have used the internal comparators. Of course I could attach an external reference to decouple the circuit from the MCU, but I want to investigate whether there is anything I could do internally.

(Edit)
A portion of the application circuit is below. Essentially, the Vref+ output buffer from the STM32 is used in a high side current sense comparator circuit. The STM32 DAC which is referenced to VREF+ is used to regulate a low sense current sense drive. If the VREF+ goes above 2.5 V, then it scales the high side sense as the low side driver drives for current through. I want to know whether it is remotely possible to detect this internally within the STM32L552.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fItJGQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Any suggestions regarding hardware configurations, ADC settings, or software approaches are highly appreciated.

Comment: What does the circuit look like? What do you power the STM32 with?

Comment: @VoltageSpike, I added a circuit of where the VREF+ output and DAC output is used. To answer your power question, the STM32 is powered by a PMIC (nPM1100) operating in buck mode. The PMIC source is either a LiPo battery or from the USB bus if plugged in.

Comment: If it was saftey critical, an external reference would solve the problem, also as long as you supply the correct power to the analog portion of the STM32, it's unlikely to have brownouts on the VREF.

Comment: On power up, I can do a self check to compare the factory measured VREFINT as stored in flash with the ADC1 internal VREFINT measurement. When VREF+ is shorted to rail, its evident that the error between the measured and factory VREFINT increases, so I know there is an issue. Other than that, I cannot think of any other internal check. Nonetheless you are right, it is best to use external reference.